# GCD by repetitive subtraction too slow

Tags: assembly, mips

I was using MIPSMARK to test my code written in MIPS Assembly. The first three tests pass without incident, however the fourth case that gets tested by MIPSMARK fails with the following error message:

MARKFILE ERROR 3. Executable fails (infinite): ./markcase.a
case 4 FAILS

```
#/*# MIPSMARK 1.0 1/5/98 Copyright 1998 J. Waldron. */
#
## Question:
## Write a function "gcd" that takes two
## numbers in $a0 and $a1, and returns their
## greatest common divisor. Both numbers will
## be greater than zero.
## Use Euclid's algorithm, based upon
##    gcd(a, a) = a
##    gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a)
##    gcd(a, b) = gcd(a-b, b) {use with a>b}
##
#/*# Output format must be:     */
#/*# "GCD is = 3"       */
#include <stdio.h>       /* for printf in C programs */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for exit() in C programs */


#/*##############################################
#                       #
#       text segment            #
#                       #
#################################################

    .text       
        .globl __start 
__start:        # execution starts here  */

        la $a0,ans
        li $v0,4
        syscall

        li $a0,39
        li $a1,24
        jal gcd 

        move $a0,$v0
        li $v0,1
        syscall 

        la $a0,endl 
        li $v0,4    
        syscall

    exit:   
        li $v0,10
        syscall     

#/* Any changes above this line will be discarded by
# mipsmark. Put your answer between dashed lines. */
#/*-------------- start cut ----------------------- */

#/*  Student's Name:   Account:     */


    gcd:
        beq $a0, $a1, done  #if "a" ($a0) is finally equal to "b" ($a1), proceeds to "exit"
        sgt  $v0, $a1, $a0      #is the value of "b" greater than "a"?
        bne $v0, $zero, loop    #if true: proceeds to "loop", if false: continues on

        subu $a0, $a0, $a1  #subtracts "b" from "a" (b < a)
        b gcd           #returns back to "gcd" and repeats

    loop:
        subu $a1, $a1, $a0  #Subtracts "a" from "b" (a < b)
        b gcd           #returns back to "gcd" and repeats
        
    done:
        move $v0, $a0       #return "a"
        jr $ra          
        
        

#/*
    j __start   #nasty loop if mips program not exited */
#/*--------------  end cut  -----------------------
# Any changes below this line will be discarded by
# mipsmark. Put your answer between dashed lines.

#################################################
#                                               #
#               data segment                    #
#                                               #
#################################################

        .data           #*/
ans:    .asciiz "GCD is = "
endl:   .asciiz "\n"
#
```

Comment: What values have you tried in your testing?  Maybe we can suggest some additional ones.

Comment: Case 1 (shown in the code above) has values of 24 and 39, which gave the correct result of 3. Case 2 was 111 and 47

Comment: But surely you have tried some other values on your own outside of the cases, no?

Comment: Ok yes. So case 4 has values of 987654320 and 12. I believe that the error is stemming from the size of the former value which causes the marker to time out. I think it has to do with efficiency. Do you have any suggestions that could help remedy this?

Comment: `sgt` isn't a hardware instruction; it has to get emulated probably with 2 instructions.  (`slt` is a real instruction, so use it.)  Also, you could probably restructure to put `bne` at the *bottom* of one loop instead of an unconditional `b`.

Comment: Much more importantly, for inputs with one large and one small number, this basically boils down to repeated subtraction for *many* iterations, so it's *much* slower than division to find the remainder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Euclidean_division).  Hardware `divu` is not fast, but it's much better than a `sub` loop for `987654320 / 12`.

Comment: Are you required to use repetitive subtraction instead of hardware division or modulo? If you need it to use repetitive subtraction, the shortest possible sequence for a an appropriate subtraction loop is 3 instructions. You have 6 currently, so you could potentially double the speed, but that may not be enough, and, to do far better, you'd have to make changes the algorithm (e.g. to subtract multiples, instead of singletons, at first),

Answer (score 2):

Using a better algorithm is the best approach for improving performance.  In general, one way to make something faster is to have it do less work.  (Another way is to pre-organize the data, but I'm not applying that approach here.)

Below are three different implementations of greatest common divisor (for positive input) using repetitive subtraction.  The following table summarizes the iterations done by each algorithm on the 987654320, 12 test case.

| Algorithm | Iterations | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gcd0 | 82304528 | largely the way you're doing it |
| gcd1 | 82304527 + 1 | cycle optimized, but largely same algorithm |
| gcd2 | 238 | subtracts multiples instead of individuals |

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd0 ( int a, int b ) {
    int iter = 0;
    while ( a != b ) {
        iter++;
        if ( a > b )
            a -= b;
        else 
            b -= a;
    }
    printf ( "iter %d\n", iter );
    return a;
}

int gcd1 ( int a, int b ) {
    int iter1 = 0;
    int iter2 = 0;
    for (;;) {
        while ( a > b ) {
            iter1++;
            a -= b;
        }
        while ( a < b ) {
            iter2++;
            b -= a;
        }
        if ( a == b ) break;
    }
    printf ( "iter1 %d, iter2 %d\n", iter1, iter2 );
    return a;
}

int gcd2 ( int a, int b ) {
    int iter1a = 0, iter1b = 0;
    int iter2a = 0, iter2b = 0;
    for (;;) {
        while ( a > b ) {
            iter1a++;
            int x = b;
            int t = x << 1;
            while ( a > t ) {
                iter1b++;
                x = t;
                t <<= 1;
            }
            a -= x;
        }
        while ( a < b ) {
            iter2a++;
            int x = a;
            int t = x << 1;
            while ( t < b ) {
                iter2b++;
                x = t;
                t <<= 1;
            }
            b -= x;
        }
        if ( a == b ) break;
    }
    printf ( "iter1a %d, iter1b %d; iter2a %d, iter2b %d\n", 
                 iter1a, iter1b, iter2a, iter2b );
    return a;
}

int main () {
    printf ("%d %d %d %d %d\n", 24, 39, gcd0(24,39), gcd1(24,39), gcd2(24,39));
    printf ("%d %d %d %d %d\n", 111, 47, gcd0(111,47), gcd1(111,47), gcd2(111,47));
    printf ("%d %d %d %d %d\n", 987654320 , 12, gcd0(987654320, 12), gcd1(987654320, 12), gcd2(987654320, 12));
    return 0;
}
```

Discussion:

`gcd0` reflects what you're doing, which is a single subtraction of `a` from `b` or `b` from `a` each iteration.  Within each iteration, a decision is made of which subtraction to perform, as well as an equality test to exit looping.

`gcd1`, for (large) input as in your example, extracts the conditional to choose whether subtracting `a` from `b` vs. `b` from `a` from each iteration of the subtraction loop; here I've structured this as three loops (one outer with `a==b` and two inner), none the less, this structure allows reducing the main work of either innermost loop to 3 instructions on MIPS.

`gcd2` works like `gcd1` except first scales the smaller value so as to subtract the largest possible power of 2 multiple of that lower value, to reduce iterations & total work being done.  Thus, when `a` is larger than `b`, it computes, by doubling `b` repeatedly, the largest value of 2<sup>N</sup>*b that can be subtracted.  On this example, it takes 220 iterations of computing the best N across 17 total subtractions — it's doing the same work of subtracting `b` from `a` until it would otherwise go negative, but clearly is doing much less actual work that `gcd1` or `gcd0`.

The doubling approach quickly identifies a large multiples that can be subtracted at once.  It also avoids multiplication, which is expensive on LC-3.

---

The final shift to scale the smaller value is also difficult on LC-3 as it can only shift by 1 at a time.  A solution here would be to save the immediately prior value (of `t`) during doubling instead of recomputing it; I've updated the answer with that.

Comment: Neat idea with shifting.  Instead of counting a shift count, though, perhaps just remember the previous iteration's `t` and subtract that?  Or always subtract as you're going, so instead of subtracting a power-of-2 multiple, you're subtracting `(2^n - 1) * b` for a possibly-different stopping point.  i.e. `0xfff... * b`.  I tried both ways in one part of `gcd3` on https://godbolt.org/z/rr8f3exoT, also taking advantage of signed integers to do `while( (a-=t) > 0 ) t<<=1;`  / `a += t;` so it can compile to `bgtz` in the loop, undoing the overshoot. I *think* that might be safe :P

Comment: Hardware remainder might still be faster, especially on newer machines with faster HW division.

Comment: @PeterCordes, right but this is/was an exercise in repetitive subtraction...

Comment: Oh, yes I guess the `a-b` part was explicit, not just Euclid's Algorithm.  The latter is compatible with using division.  Regardless, it's still interesting to see if this approaches the speed of HW remainder.  I'd guess it's not bad, but it's computing the exact remainder so it's doing the same work as `div`.  Maybe faster for numbers of similar magnitude, though, which may be more common with GCD than the general case of division.